# Eclipse: "Configured resource" on a Server italic or not (Add and Remove...-Dialog)

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, tomcat, server, wildfly

In Eclipse one can deploy applications to a configured server by using RMT on the server (within the `Servers` view) and choose `Add and Remove`.

I wonder what it means when a resource name is rendered in *italic* rather than normal, after adding it to the `Configured` side, on the right.

I assume it has something to do with resource synchronisation, but sometimes it seems not to.

Here's a screenshot, to clarify:

[image: non-italic vs. italic resource name]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I'm also in doubt about this. I ended up right-clicking the server instance and clicking the "Clean..." option. The resource name changed back to normal.